# Overlays with subtitle with multiple text in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following query. please find images
I have two inputs one is bg.png,( background-color), another one is  baby webm
with two texts one is "Double click to edit" which back of baby.webm and other "adi" which overlayed on baby.webm

My command is

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i bg.png -vcodec libvpx-vp9 -stream_loop -1 -i baby.webm -y -filter_complex "[0]subtitles=subs.ass:fontsdir=/fonts/Dancing_Script.ttf[sub];[1:v]scale=1076:606[scale1];[scale1]rotate=0:c=black@0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[rotate1];[sub][rotate1]overlay=x=684.57:y=357.98,subtitles=subs.ass:fontsdir=/fonts/Times_New_Roman-400.ttf" -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 10 ip.mp4
```

But the output I got is

If you check the difference text overlay pattern, there is a difference in an overlay pattern. How can I achieve output the same as the input?

above is .ass file

```
[Script Info]
; Script generated by Aegisub 3.2.2
; http://www.aegisub.org/
Title: Default Aegisub file
ScriptType: v4.00+
WrapStyle: 0
ScaledBorderAndShadow: no
YCbCr Matrix: None
PlayResX: 1920
PlayResY: 1080

[Aegisub Project Garbage]
Last Style Storage: Default

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Dancing Script,121.1,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,1
Style: Default,Times New Roman,216,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,1


[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:05.00,Default,,0,0,0,,Double click to edit {\fnDancing Script\pos(430,514)}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:05.00,Default,,0,0,0,,Adi {\fnTimes New Roman\pos(1051,681)\fs216}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) and [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex "subtitles=subs1.ass[bg];[bg][1]overlay,subtitles=subs2.ass" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks,I have query could you please tell, if subtitle does suits for below scenerio
1. user adds video as input first.
2. on top of video a text with some X font family from directory.
3.partially on top text an image .
4.and then text on it with another font family

Does Subtitle filter suits perfectly for multiple overlay? does it affect on perfomance? If possible how can we acheive that?( can we add multiple .ass file for that or any simple solution.

Comment: Something like the below command , Not working cmd but trying to overlay multiple text ..Am i wrong ?
ffmpeg -i bg.png -i test.mp4 -i test.png -y -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1210:682[scale1];[scale1]rotate=0:c=black@0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[rotate0];[0:v][rotate0]overlay=x=291.12:y=206.9[overlay0];[overlay0]subtitles=test.ass,overlay=x=291.12:y=206.9[textoverlay10];[2:v]scale=630:354[scale2];[scale2]rotate=0:c=black@0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[rotate2];[textoverlay10][rotate2]overlay=x=737.13:y=50.87[overlay2];[overlay2]subtitles=test.ass,overlay=x=291.12:y=206.9" -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 10 ver.mp4

Comment: new questionnaire https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927560/overlay-in-ffmpeg-with-subtitle

Comment: @KonduriSaiAditya It was not clear in your original question that you wanted subtitles, overlay, **and then subtitles**. See updated answer. Please be more descriptive and clear in your questions. The constant follow-up questions for each of my answers for you are time consuming. You'll get better answers faster if I don't have to always guess.

Comment: @Ilogan Could you please check my updated question. sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I tried with two separate .ass files, It worked fine. But is there any scope with one .ass file with all text included in it with the same output result?

Comment: @KonduriSaiAditya Not possible. Use 2 separate .ass files.