# Overlay in ffmpeg with subtitle

Tags: ffmpeg

[image][image: below is the image for similar command]I am struck with overlaying image and subtitles in FFmpeg, above is the command

```
ffmpeg -i bg.png -vcodec libvpx-vp9 -i test.webm -i test.png -y -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1210:682[scale1];[scale1]rotate=0:c=black@0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[rotate0];[0:v][rotate0]overlay=x=291.12:y=206.9[overlay0];[overlay0]subtitles=test.ass,overlay=x=291.12:y=206.9[textoverlay10];[2:v]scale=630:354[scale2];[scale2]rotate=0:c=black@0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[rotate2];[textoverlay10][rotate2]overlay=x=737.13:y=50.87[overlay2];[overlay2]subtitles=test.ass,overlay=x=291.12:y=206.9" -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 10 ver.mp4
```

I am getting the following error "Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_subtitles_3".Is this the correct way of overlay images, and subtitles? please correct me where I am going wrong.

If I add an image on top of it[image: This image is similar to the command i mentioned above], please find below image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Simplified example from your command

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.png -i bird.webm -filter_complex "[0]subtitles=subs.ass[bg];[bg][1]overlay=shortest=1,format=yuv420p" output.mp4
```

## Example you can copy and paste

[image]

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=red:s=320x240,format=yuv444p -f lavfi -i color=c=green:s=280x200,format=yuv444p -f lavfi -i color=c=blue@0.5:s=80x80,format=yuva444p -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,subtitles=subs.ass:fontsdir=/tmp/font[bg];[bg][2]overlay=10:10:format=auto,format=yuv420p" -t 10 output.mp4
```

- Using [color filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color) for synthetic inputs (the red, green, and blue boxes).
- [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) to place the green and blue boxes.
- [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) to place subtitles.
- [format filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) is used to prevent chroma-subsampling induced blurryness and to enable alpha/transparency for blue box.
- `fontsdir` option was used in this example to locate external fonts. `fontsdir` can be omitted if you want to use fonts already installed in your system.

#### subs.ass for above example

```
[Script Info]
; Script generated by Aegisub 3.2.2
; http://www.aegisub.org/
Title: Default Aegisub file
ScriptType: v4.00+
WrapStyle: 0
ScaledBorderAndShadow: yes
YCbCr Matrix: None

[Aegisub Project Garbage]
Last Style Storage: Default

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Bradley Hand,28,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,2,2,7,10,10,10,1

[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:05.00,Default,,0,0,0,,Line 1: Bradley Hand font\N{\fnComic Sans MS}Line 2: Comic Sans MS font{\fn}\NLine 3: Bradley Hand font
```

- Subtitles were positioned with [`Alignment`](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/#%5Can) option in ASS file.
- Default font was set with `Fontname` option in ASS file.
- Font for Line 2 was set using [`\fn` override tag](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/#%5Cfn).

Comment: But test.png is overlaying two times with the above command

Comment: Actually my cmd with drawatext filter,
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i bg.png -vcodec libvpx-vp9 -stream_loop -1 -i test.webm -y -filter_complex [1:v]scale=1018:574[scale1];[scale1]rotate=0:c=black@0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[rotate0];[0:v][rotate0]overlay=x=369.5:y=173.03[overlay0];color=black@0:959x137[c10],[c10]setsar=1,drawtext=fontfile=Times_New_Roman.ttf:text=Double click to edit:fontsize=121.19999999999999:fontcolor=#1e8bc3:line_spacing=16.916000000000007,rotate=0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0):c=black@0[rottext10],[overlay0][rottext10]overlay=x=373.97:y=447.096:shortest=1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 10 out.mp4

Comment: Need to change with subtitle filter

Comment: I need the above with subtitle filter

Comment: @KonduriSaiAditya I could tell you to simply replace `drawtext` with `subtitles`, but I doubt you would find that satisfactory. I am not completely sure what you are trying to do here. If you provide an image example showing the desired result I can try to provide the command. Also, what is the point of the rotate filters? They are set to 0 so do nothing.

Comment: uploaded the image ,i want the similar output through subtitle

Comment: For the above image, i am able to render output with drawtext filter, but multi-line alignment calculation is getting complexity.SO any chance with subtitles, that might be clean?

Comment: @KonduriSaiAditya I don't understand your question.

Comment: means on top of text if I add an image, overlaying it is enough? (command mentioned in the question for reference )

Comment: @KonduriSaiAditya Yes, overlay is enough...if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Actually I had overlayed an image on top of text, did you checked that upload?

Comment: Does subtitle which is overlaying on video is with respect  to input first image or chained output(2 nd input)

Comment: @KonduriSaiAditya Because you did not supply any individual input files I assumed the baby and red color were 1 image: `background.png`. My command places subtitles over background and `bird.webm` over subtitles. This assumes that you have proper placement or alignment in the ASS file.

Comment: @KonduriSaiAditya Seems you require an answer you can copy and paste. Answer updated.